# Can't mount cds after failed Brasero burn

Tags: mount, automount, cd-drive, brasero

Brasero failed to burn a disk recently, and now I can't access CD-ROMS. Even CD-Rs are not not showing.
Using Ubuntu 11.10 on a Dell D510 Lattitude laptop.

```
allan@allan-Latitude-D510:~$ cdrecord -checkdrive
Device was not specified. Trying to find an appropriate drive...
Detected CD-R drive: /dev/cdrw
Using /dev/cdrom of unknown capabilities
Device type    : Removable CD-ROM
Version        : 5
Response Format: 2
Capabilities   : 
Vendor_info    : 'TSSTcorp'
Identification : 'DVD+-RW TS-L532B'
Revision       : 'DE04'
Device seems to be: Generic mmc2 DVD-R/DVD-RW.
Using generic SCSI-3/mmc   CD-R/CD-RW driver (mmc_cdr).
Driver flags   : MMC-3 SWABAUDIO BURNFREE 
Supported modes: TAO PACKET SAO SAO/R96P SAO/R96R RAW/R96R
```

My CD drive is now useless, and any help on getting it to read/burn would be appreciated.

Comment: laptop burners are relatively cheap these days.  £25 or thereabouts last time I checked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I tried booting from a Windows cd I know works.
Drive light stays on but nobody's home.

It appears my drive is fubar.

Time for a new laptop.

Wonder if I can get a discount without Windows ;)